# Why can't gdb read io_uring_cqe contents?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, eventqueue, io-uring

I am trying out [loti-examples](https://github.com/shuveb/loti-examples) (Lord of the Uring) commit 8724d47 and liburing commit 7ff4fee on Ubuntu 20.04 with mainline kernel 5.12.

I use the following patch for loti-examples to have a better debugging experience:

```text
diff --git a/CMakeLists.txt b/CMakeLists.txt
index 0c857b6..0afcbe3 100644
--- a/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -2,6 +2,8 @@ cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
 project(liburing_examples C)
 
 set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
+set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
+SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ggdb3") 
 
 add_executable(probe probe.c)
 target_link_libraries(probe uring)
```

After building, I launch `gdb build/webserver_liburing`, here is what I am doing:

```
(gdb) start
[omitted]
(gdb) break io_uring_sqe_set_data
Breakpoint 2 at 0x5555555556ec: file /usr/include/liburing.h, line 200.
(gdb) break 441
Breakpoint 3 at 0x555555556acb: file /home/janus/Skrivebord/artemis/loti-examples/webserver_liburing.c, line 441.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Minimum kernel version required is: 5.5
Your kernel version is: 5.12
ZeroHTTPd listening on port: 8000

Breakpoint 2, io_uring_sqe_set_data (sqe=0x7ffff7fc2000, data=0x55555555c6b0) at /usr/include/liburing.h:200
200     sqe->user_data = (unsigned long) data;
(gdb) p data
$1 = (void *) 0x55555555c6b0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, server_loop (server_socket=3) at /home/janus/Skrivebord/artemis/loti-examples/webserver_liburing.c:441
441         struct request *req = (struct request *) io_uring_cqe_get_data(cqe);
(gdb) p cqe->user_data
Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7fc6140
(gdb) p ret
$5 = 0
```

I am trying to verify that the `request` pointer that is sent on the submission queue is the same one that comes back on the the completion queue.

So at the breakpoint at [line 441](https://github.com/shuveb/loti-examples/blob/8724d47a67b9b4c402552c4a90a64cfdad56039e/webserver_liburing.c#L441), you can see from the last line of gdb output, that the call to `io_uring_wait_cqe` was successful, since its return value `ret` is zero. So why can't I read `cqe->user_data` with gdb? I'd expect it to contain the same address that was submitted to the submission queue on the first breakpoint, bound to the name `data` at that time.

EDIT May 12th:

Mark Plotnick hinted that the address could be I/O mapped, and indeed it is:

```
(gdb) x cqe
0x7ffff7fc6140: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7fc6140
(gdb) info proc mappings
[...]
  0x7ffff7fc2000     0x7ffff7fc6000     0x4000 0x10000000 anon_inode:[io_uring]
  0x7ffff7fc6000     0x7ffff7fc9000     0x3000        0x0 anon_inode:[io_uring]
[...]
```

Comment: _If_ `user_data` is a _pointer_, it's complaining about the value of `cqe` itself.

Comment: @CraigEstey right, I can't read `cqe` either. Why not?

Comment: What error do you get when you type `p cqe` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The same error. "Cannot access memory"

Comment: Is cqe in an area of memory that is mapped to an I/O device?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Indeed it is, I added an edit that shows it. Why won't gdb show it to me if it has been I/O mapped?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I vaguely recall a question with similar circumstances appearing here in [gdb] a few years ago.  I think the failure occurs when the device driver doesn't implement one of the file_operations required by `ptrace`, which is the system call that GDB uses to access process memory. I will look for the dup.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If you'd like to submit an answer saying that it is ptrace related, I would accept that.